# Move item to a different layer using script in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, illustrator-scripting, javascript

This may be a something I skipped over in my search, but can anyone show me how to add an item to a layer using a JavaScript Adobe Illustrator script?

Also, are there any good resources for learning how to write scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: The layer, and other objects has a method called `move` this allows you move the object to specific position in hierarchy. And yes the name may be bad since its ambigious as to wether it moves in space or hierarchy

Comment: All space moves are called transforms... So not exactly normal reading comprehension. And no there are no good resources to learn scripting. But again that is because learning scripting is just the same as using illustrator in first place. If you know how to program and use illustrator you know illustrator scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's two questions really, the first one, here's a sample to move the selected objects to a different layer named new_layer:

```
var docSelected = app.activeDocument.selection;  
var targetLayer = app.activeDocument.layers["new_layer"];

for (s = 0; s < docSelected.length; s++) {  
     myPath = docSelected[s];
     myPath.move(targetLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
}
```

The second questions, there's no great resource for learning scripting, but there's plenty of info on the web and on pdf on the adobe website.

[Scriptographer - One of the best resources, with tutorials, samples, etc..](https://scriptographer.org/tutorials/)

[In github - Quick Intro](https://github.com/rjduran/adobe-scripting)

[Adobe - Manuals in pdf format from adobe](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html)

[Readthedocs - Wiki with a lot of info for scripting](https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/)

[Medium - A very very basic intro to scripting in illustrator](https://medium.com/@jtnimoy/illustrator-scripting-tutorial-d626297b1df7)